# Download file saved as base64

Tags: javascript, download, base64

I need to download files that are saved as `base64` string. The file can be of any type.

I've tried to make `window.open(prefix + base64);` where prefix is a string that JS Reader generates when reading `asDataUrl`. However, downloading file with prefix `data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document;base64,` resulted in file that has no extension.

What can be done here? (I have to use base64 as a source)

Answer (score 3):

You can make an `<a download>` in JavaScript and click it to suggest a filename:

```js
document.getElementById('download').onclick = () => {
    const base64 = '';  // …
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = 'data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document;base64,' + base64;
    link.download = 'my-document.docx';
    link.click();
};
```

```html
<button type="button" id="download">Download</button>
```

Although I don’t know which browsers don’t recognize that media type as .docx, so maybe they don’t support the `download` attribute either.

Comment: Where am I supposed to get `.docx` extension etc?

Comment: @Sergey: You mean it’s not always a .docx? The prefix changes as well?

Comment: As I've mentioned in the first line of my question it can be any file of any type. That's the main problem.

Comment: @Sergey: Can’t be done in general. You can supplement the browser with your own mapping of types to extensions, but there’s no way to convert one into the other without a mapping (otherwise the browser would already be doing it).